# How to receive data sent by Ajax in post request in a .jsp file

Tags: jquery, jsp

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "serverHistoryView.jsp",
  data: {
    "serverName": serverName,
    "startDate": startDate,
    "endDate": endDate
  },
  contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",

  success: function(data) {

    $("#response").html("");
    $("#response").html(data);
  }
});

I can get the data on JSP 
String serverName=request.getParameter("serverName");
```

But when i am trying to do same thing through post request.I am unable to get the ajax data on serverHistoryView.jsp . What should i do?

Comment: add more information on the OP or be down voted to oblivion.

Comment: in get request i can get the parameter.But when i am trying to do with Post  it is getting null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using "data.d" instead of "data"

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "serverHistoryView.jsp",
  data: {
    "serverName": serverName,
    "startDate": startDate,
    "endDate": endDate
  },
  contentType: "application/html; charset=utf-8",

  success: function(data) {

    $("#response").html("");
    $("#response").html(data.d);
  }
});
```